# dnsmasq: failed to create IPset control socket: Permission denied

Tags: dnsmasq

When I start dnsmasq service in CentOS 7, I get such status:

[image]

This is because I add a wblist.conf in /etc/dnsmasq.d/wblist.conf

> cat wblist.conf

```
# for router itself
server=/google.com.tw/192.168.8.20#53
ipset=/google.com.tw/gfwlist
```

> ipset -L gfwlist

```
Name: gfwlist
Type: hash:net
Revision: 3
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536
Size in memory: 16784
References: 0
Members:
```

But if I COMMENT the ipset line, the service can be restarted successfully.

I don't know why. I have used dnsmasq/ipset for a long time, but suddenly got this problem.

Have anyone met this situation?

Comment: I found this article [SELinux prevents ipset from creating a netlink socket](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1290705), and I disabled SELinux, then it worked. I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable SElinux is not recommend.

You can solve this problem by create and install a SELinux Policy Modules.

First you need create a *type enforcement* rules file called **my-dnsmasq.te**, content like below:

```sh
module my-dnsmasq 1.0;

require {
        type dnsmasq_t;
        class netlink_socket { bind create write };
}

#============= dnsmasq_t ==============
allow dnsmasq_t self:netlink_socket { bind create write };
```

Now you can compile it into a policy module package file:

```sh
checkmodule -M -m -o my-dnsmasq.mod my-dnsmasq.te
semodule_package -o my-dnsmasq.pp -m my-dnsmasq.mod
```

Once you get the policy module package file **my-dnsmasq.pp**, install it:

```sh
sudo semodule -i my-dnsmasq.pp
```

Finally, restart the **dnsmasq.service**:

```sh
sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
```

And make a test like below:

```sh
nslookup google.com.tw
ipset list gfwlist
```

If everything is fine, you will see a ip is added to ipset.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a custom SELinux module, there is an SELinux boolean to enable ipset:

```
sudo setsebool -P dnsmasq_use_ipset 1
```

Using -P will make the change persistent.

Answer (score -3):

I found this article SELinux prevents ipset from creating a netlink socket, and I disabled SELinux, then it worked. I don't know why.